# API não recebe post com lista

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, knockoutjs

Tenho uma API que recebe um post, se eu receber apenas um único contrato, ela recebe os dados normalmente:

```
    [HttpPost("GravaContratos")]
    public async Task<JsonResult> GravaContratos(ContratoModel contrato)
    {
       //faz alguma coisa...

    }
```

Post em javascript enviando só um registro:

```
      $.post("/api/Contratos/GravaContratos/", that.Contratos()[0])
       .done(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
      });
```

Mas se eu enviar uma lista ou um objeto que contenha uma lista, ela não está recebendo.
Já tentei enviar direto a lista:

```
     $.post("/api/Contratos/GravaContratos/", that.Contratos())
      .done(function (response) {
           console.log(response);
     });
```

Ou como objeto:

```
   var lista = {
        Contratos: that.Contratos()
   }

   $.post("/api/Contratos/GravaContratos/", lista )
     .done(function (response) {
          console.log(response);
    });
```

E na API eu tentei receber a lista:

```
    [HttpPost("GravaContratos")]
    public async Task<JsonResult> GravaContratos(<List>ContratoModel contrato)
    {
       //faz alguma coisa...

    }
```

Ou receber o objeto:

```
    [HttpPost("GravaContratos")] // dentro da model tem uma lista de contratos
    public async Task<JsonResult> GravaContratos(ContratoListaModel contrato)
    {
       //faz alguma coisa...

    }
```

Mas de jeito nenhum eu consigo receber a lista de contratos, não sei qual é o problema, já fiz outros cadastros assim e funcionam sem problemas.

Model de contratos (Modelo simples para teste):

```
  public class ContratoModel
  {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public string DataReajuste { get; set; }

    public string DataFinal { get; set; }

    public decimal Valor { get; set; }

    public string NomeLocatario { get; set; }

    public string NomeProprietario { get; set; }

    public string NomeContrato { get; set; }

    public string NomeImovel { get; set; }
}
```

Json enviado da lista:

```
 [
  {
   "Id":"4cd0cd37-1768-43fb-1a4b-08d3baf8b9e0",
   "Nome":null,
   "DataReajuste":null,
   "DataFinal":null,
   "Valor":316.67,
   "NomeLocatario":"Cliente teste",
   "NomeProprietario":"Cliente teste",
   "NomeContrato":"Contrato Um",
   "NomeImovel":"teste",
 {
  "Id":"a86c2c21-9727-453c-605f-08d3c7645118",
  "Nome":null,
  "DataReajuste":null,
  "DataFinal":null,
  "Valor":800,
  "NomeLocatario":"Cliente teste",
  "NomeProprietario":"Cliente teste",
  "NomeContrato":"Contrato dois",
  "NomeImovel":"teste"
 }
]
```

Json enviado do objeto:

```
 {"Contratos":[
  {
   "Id":"4cd0cd37-1768-43fb-1a4b-08d3baf8b9e0",
   "Nome":null,
   "DataReajuste":null,
   "DataFinal":null,
   "Valor":316.67,
   "NomeLocatario":"Cliente teste",
   "NomeProprietario":"Cliente teste",
   "NomeContrato":"Contrato Um",
   "NomeImovel":"teste",
 {
  "Id":"a86c2c21-9727-453c-605f-08d3c7645118",
  "Nome":null,
  "DataReajuste":null,
  "DataFinal":null,
  "Valor":800,
  "NomeLocatario":"Cliente teste",
  "NomeProprietario":"Cliente teste",
  "NomeContrato":"Contrato dois",
  "NomeImovel":"teste"
 }
]
}
```

Tentei um post utilizando `$.ajax`, mas não recebeu também:

```
 var settings = {
            "async": true,
            "crossDomain": true,
            "url": "/api/Contratos/GravaContratos/",
            "method": "POST",
            "headers": {
                "content-type": "application/json",
                "cache-control": "no-cache"
            },
            "processData": false,
            "data": that.Contratos()
        }

        $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
```

Como posso receber a lista?

Comment: `$.post` é diferente utilizar data, use `$.ajax` com metodo `method: 'POST'` e `data: {variavel de valor}` este data para colocar o valor de post, e outra coisa se colocou `that.Contratos()[0]` e não entendi.

Comment: Eu tentei fazer com `$.ajax`, também não recebeu, vou atualizar a pergunta, Contratos é um `observableArray` do `knockout`, com `that.Contratos()[0]` estou enviando o objeto da primeira posição.

Comment: Se esta retornado o valor? se for não retornou e era isso problema, vai segue seu ajax antes parentese e adicione `return {variavel resultado}` e tente mais uma vez.

Comment: Eu estou debugando a API e lá recebe como `null` ou como uma lista vazia, o problema não é no retorno.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema era que eu tinha uma model com uma lista de contratos dentro, assim:

```
public class ContratoListaModel{

    public IEnumerable<Contrato> Contrato { get; set; }

}
```

E estava recebendo na API o paramentro com o mesmo nome:

```
[HttpPost("GravaContratos")] 
public async Task<JsonResult> GravaContratos(ContratoListaModel contrato)
{
   //faz alguma coisa...

}
```

Por algum motivo quando tem os nomes iguais, a API não recebe, mesmo tendo a diferença entre maiúscula e minuscula, eu alterei o nome do parametro da API e recebeu normal.

Answer (score 0):

No parametro data do seu ajax tenta o seguinte:

```
"data": { contratos: that.Contratos() },
```

E no método correspondente:

```
public async Task<JsonResult> GravaContratos(List<ContratoModel> contratos)
```